Google Sheets Addon stops working when changing the request URL
I developed a Google Sheets Add-on that makes some requests to my server by using UrlFetchApp. The Add-on is deployed to the Google Marketplace. Everything works fine until I change the URL after the first deployment. So when using api.domain.com it is working fine. But now I would like to use another server api2.domain.com which has a different IP. I receive 500 error when making a request.
I assumed that the IP of the new server is not white-listed so I searched around but could not find any settings to do that. The new server is working fine, that is not the problem. When I test the Add-on, it also works with new server URL. It only stops working after the deployment.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example and other details so the community can understand the issue further.
